# strcmp() function not working for the word "university"

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, multidimensional-array

So in this small project for my school I needed to build a word guessing game everything works fine except the string university which always gives output incorrect, I tried changing it to universit and it works but university doesn't work. I cant figure out what the problem is.

Also are there any other alternatives to `strcmp()`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ // at first we are basically going to give an intro to the gameseco
    cout << "   HANGMAN : GUESS THE WORD AND NOT DIE!!\n\n\n";

    cout << "   Welcome to the game player!!\n\n";
    cout << "   Rules: Guess the word by typing a letter based on given hints.\n";
    cout << "                  Multiple incorrect guesses will HANG YOU.\n\n";

    // here we add different words in the game for the guessing system using a 2 dimensional array 
char word[20][20] = {
        "higher",
        "secondary",
        "first",
        "year",
        "cotton",
        "university",
        "computer",
        "science",
        "project",
        "hangman",
    };

    char newword[20], guess[10];
    bool again = 1;

    while (again == 1)
    {

        again = 0;
        srand(time(0));
        int x = 0, wrong = 0, z = (rand() % 10) + 0;
        strcpy(newword, word[z]); // so we used strcpy command to copy an element of the 2D array of randomly generated index to a new string

        cout << "Enter your guess. \nHINT: Word Length(indicated by underscores) = "; // hint no. one the gives us the exact lenth of word

        for (x = 0; newword[x] != '\0'; x++)
        {
            cout << "-";
        }
        cout << "\nWord starts with: '" << newword[0] << "'"; // hint no. two which gives the player an idea what the word might be

        cout << "\n\n";

        for (wrong = 1; wrong <= 6; wrong++) // the loop here checks whether the input given by the user is correct or not
        {
            cin >> guess; // the input is taken here

            if (strcmp(guess, newword) == 0) // the input is compared with the word to be guessed
            {                                // using the strcmp() function from the string.h library

                cout << "Correct!\n"; // if the guess is correct the program will print correct and correct and end

                break; // correct guess will terminate the loop
            }
            else if (wrong == 1)
            {
                cout << "Opps! Wrong guess!\n\n"; // if player inputs wrong word a poll will appear for hanging the person

                cout << "I=-=\n";
                cout << "|\n";
                cout << "|\n";
                cout << "|\n";
                cout << "|\n";
                cout << "I\n";
            }
            else if (wrong == 2)
            {
                cout << "Opps! Wrong guess again!\n\n"; // each wrong word will result in the appearance of of a hanging person

                cout << "I=-=\n";
                cout << "|  |\n";
                cout << "|\n";
                cout << "|\n";
                cout << "|\n";
                cout << "I\n";
            }
            else if (wrong == 3)
            {
                cout << "Opps! Wrong guess again!\n\n";

                cout << "I=-=\n";
                cout << "|  |\n";
                cout << "|  O\n";
                cout << "|\n";
                cout << "|\n";
                cout << "I\n";
            }
            else if (wrong == 4)
            {
                cout << "Opps! Wrong guess again!\n\n";

                cout << "I=-=\n";
                cout << "|  |\n";
                cout << "|  O\n";
                cout << "I--|--\n";
                cout << "|\n";
                cout << "I\n";
            }
            else if (wrong == 5)
            {
                cout << "Opps! Wrong guess again!\n\n";

                cout << "I=-=\n";
                cout << "|  |\n";
                cout << "|  O\n";
                cout << "I--|--\n";
                cout << "|  o\n";
                cout << "I\n";
            }
            else if (wrong == 6)
            {
                cout << "Opps! Wrong guess again!\nLast Chance!!\n\n"; // unfortunately the player couldn't guess the word

                cout << "I=-=\n";
                cout << "|  |\n";
                cout << "|  O\n"; // the hanging person compeletely appears and the program ends
                cout << "|--|--\n";
                cout << "|  o\n";
                cout << "I | |\n";
                cout << "YOU ARE DEAD HAHAHA!!!";
            }
        }
        cout << "Do you want to play again?\nPress 1 for yes, 0 for no."; // here it is asked if we want to play again

        cin >> again;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `guess` array (10 chars) is not big enough to hold "university" (11 chars - including the nul terminator).

Comment: You should call `srand` once, at the beginning of your program, and never in a loop. Also, the language you are writing in is called C-with-iostreams. Bear in mind that iostreams is probably one of the worst parts of C++. I recommend writing in either proper C or proper C++.

Comment: When you use C++11 or later strncmp isn't needed anymore, just compare two std::string instances. Also in C++ srand has been replaced with types from https://en.cppreference.com/ w/cpp/numeric/random  (you have control over distributions as well). Aything char[] in your code should be std::string and, char[][] should be std::vector<std::string>. If your teacher has issues with that he is stil teaching C++ as it was before C++11 (which is no over 10 years old) or possibly pre C++98

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be this declaration:

```cpp
char guess[10];
```

Your array declaration should always cater for a `\0` character at the end of string. The length of **"university"** is 10 character, to hold the entire string you required an array of 11 characters.

So please change the length of `guess` array to be longest string length plus 1.

```cpp
char guess[11];
```

As a side note:
Since you are using C++, you should fully utilize the facilities offers by the language. In C++, you should use `std::string` to store array of characters, use `std::vector` to store a collection of objects etc.

Comment: Thanks i get it now actually i cant use std::string or std::vector since they would simply strike it off since it's not in syllabus